# Exception on memcpy(). I want to send a message

Tags: c++, zeromq, memcpy

```
FILE * pFile = fopen("C:\\Penguins.jpg","rb");
fseek( pFile, 0, SEEK_END );
int Size = ftell( pFile );
fseek(pFile,0,SEEK_SET);
zmq::message_t newmessage ;
memcpy((void*)newmessage.data(),pFile,Size);
requester.send(newmessage);
fclose(pFile);
```

Memcpy() out with  `Access violation (parameters: 0x00000008).` 
What to do? I tried a lot!

Comment: pfile is a file handle. it's not a memory pointer. memcpy() is for memory-to-memory, not file-to-memory. In other words, RTFM: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Comment: @MarcB Okay. But what i can do with that?

Comment: `pFile` is a pointer to a `FILE` object. The `FILE` object (whose internal details needn't concern us) contains information necessary to access a file, in this case `C:\Penguins.jpg`. Copying data from the `FILE` object makes no sense; that's not how you read from a file. You probably want to call `fread`.

Comment: The *only* things you can meaningfully do with a `FILE*` involve passing it to library functions.

Comment: What hurts me is to call this code C++.

Comment: @simkarta, you raise a good point about the anger.  A score of -4 is completely unjustified.

Comment: @slmkarta: It is not actually angry people. Simply a few people thought that this question is not good because it lacks basic understanding of the tools used. Just do not take it personally. Also, to be fair, you got handful of good comments, and a couple of nice answers!

Comment: @rodrigo Yes, the main thing I got help

Comment: Really what's wrong with the question?  All OP is (conceptually) missing is the intermediary of a memory buffer and that he can't go directly from A to B without passing through C.  The comments he got were accurate but could have, with very little extra effort, been made actually helpful.

Comment: @Duck It's just a really poor question. It's basically "I got this bug because I didn't know how to read a file. But instead of asking how to read a file, which I obviously don't know how to do and have never done successfully, I'll make you figure that out from my code." (We'll still help the person who asked it. But the question isn't interesting and won't be useful to others. So it deserves downvotes. It's not a judgment on the person who asked the question, just the question. We all sometimes ask bad questions, and if we get good answers, no harm is done.)

Comment: @David Schwartz, fair enough.  The piling on bothers me but I guess alls well that ends well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to replace the `memcpy` with:

```
  fread((char *)(newmessage.data), 1, Size, pFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the file with `memcpy`, you need to memory map the file. Since you didn't memory map the file, you need to read it with, say, `fread`.